# OS.REMOVE() not being called when deleting raster files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, raster

I am trying to remove those raster files (in tif format) with all no value data(all the value in the file is -3.4028235e+38).
However, I found the os. remove() could not work, there is no file being deleted. The print statement also didn't work.

Could somebody tell me what the problem is with the code?
Cheers

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy

directory = 'E:/data/'
for image in os.listdir(directory):
    indiv = Image.open(directory + image)
    elevMax = numpy.amax(indiv)
    print(directory + image)
    print(str(elevMax))
    if elevMax == -3.4028235e+38:
        print("it had the value")
        os.remove(os.path.join(directory, image))
```

Here are some outputs for the code:

```
E:/data/filteredN01E116.tif
1907.05
E:/data/filteredN01E117.tif
-3.4028235e+38
E:/data/filteredN01E118.tif
-3.4028235e+38
E:/data/filteredN01E119.tif
-3.4028235e+38
E:/data/filteredN01E120.tif
1693.56
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if the only clue you give is *not work*

Comment: Are you sure `os.remove()` is even being called?  I am suspicious about that floating point comparison.

Comment: Thanks, John. I try to print a statement below to see if os. remove() was being called, but it seems like nothing came out from that condition. When I get the max value from the files, some of them printed out the value of -3.4028235e+38, which makes me confused.

Comment: Thank Diego, I have edited the descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It is just the problem of the type.

```
if elevMax == numpy.float32(-3.4028235e+38):
        print("it had the value")
        os.remove(os.path.join(directory, image))
```

That works! Thanks for all of your comments.